# loading blank page despite form action location upon error

Tags: php, html, error-handling

I am creating a simple form that a user submits and email. I am trying to pose an error if the form is blank or it's not a valid email and if successful, then reload the page with a success message.

When I submit blank it reloads the page without an error, and if I enter anything in ( valid or invalid email ) it reloads the page white, despite the form action being correct. I've been stuck on this and need help. Thanks.

```
 <?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/system/init.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if(empty($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

            $error = "Please enter a valid email";

        }else{
            $success = true;    

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO survey 
                (email) VALUES('".$_POST['email']."' ) ") 
                or die(mysql_error());  
        }
    }


    ?>

<div class="email-survey">
            <?php if(isset($success)) { ?>
            <div class="success">Thank You!</div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if(isset($error)) { ?>
            <div class="error">
                <?php echo $error; ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

             <form name="settings" action="/survey-confirm.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="email" /> <br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
             </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you running your posted code as everything in the same file? If so, change `action="/survey-confirm.php"` to `action=""` see if that helps.

Comment: I ran your script without the SQL stuff and left the action blank, and it worked fine.

Comment: @Fred -ii- same thing for me. poses error if left blank but if I put in a valid email or gibberish it loads a white page

Comment: It's your SQL then. I tested your code as stated in my answer below and it worked fine. I can't duplicate your SQL entries unfortunately, that is the extent of my testing as the moment.

Comment: If I leave it blank, and hit submit, it will ask me to enter a valid email address. I tested that as well to make sure.

Comment: I think the problem may be in `(email) VALUES('".$_POST['email']."' ) ")` the way you're querying it. I'm not an SQL pro, so that part I can't help more than that, sorry.

Comment: Try using mysql_query("INSERT INTO `survey` VALUES ('$email')"); see if that helps. I Google'd it a bit and found something to that affect. SO is playing tricks on me for the backtick inclusions. I will insert it on top of my answer.

Comment: See my updated answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: Another thing, make sure you're connected to your DB, or is that in your `init.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

function control($type, $text)
{
echo '<div class="'.$type.'">'.$text.'</div>';
}

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/system/init.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if(empty($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

            control('error', 'Type valid mail!');

        }else{
            control('success', 'All done!');   

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO survey 
                (email) VALUES('".$_POST['email']."' ) ") 
                or die(mysql_error());  
        }
    }
else
{echo 'echo '<form name="settings" action="/survey-confirm.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" /> <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</div>';}

?>
```

This is small function named control, you can call this and put your custom div name and text to show user.

control('THIS IS DIV NAME','THIS IS MESSAGE FOR USER')